# Is there a way to increase the performance of symmetric matrices using Armadillo in c++?

Tags: c++, matrix, distance, armadillo

I am using Armadillo for matrix calculations in c++, in order to calculate the distance between all particles in a x,y plane. i am using below class, in which `myParticls &pSystem` is another class that holds information about all created particles.

```
    class DistMatrix
    {
        private:
            arma::Mat<float> _X;
            arma::Mat<float> _Y;


        public:

            DistMatrix(myParticls &pSystem)
            {
             _X = arma::repmat(pSystem.x(), pSystem.size(), 1);
             _Y = arma::repmat(pSystem.y(), pSystem.size(), 1);
            }

            arma::Mat<float> DistanceMatrix()
            {
                return arma::sqrt(arma::square(_X - _X.t()) + arma::square(_Y - _Y.t()));

            }

    };
```

the resulted matrix is a symmetric matrix, and by definition half of the operations i will apply to it will be wasted processing power and memory. my question is, is there a way to prevent duplicated operations to increase performance?

i tried trimming the upper part of the matrix and changing its type to sparse matrix, but that only decreased the performance. i am new to c++, and programming in general.